# not get the value of latitude and longitude in google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the GoogleMap. and It is display current position currectly but latitude and longitude are display 0.0 in system.out.println in displayMap() method. My question is why not display current latitude and longitude?

I send you my code. please check my code and suggest me that how to fetch value of current latitude and current longitude?
Button btnSubmit = null;

```
/** Use for Google Map */


private GoogleMap googleMap = null;
    private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = null;
    public double latitude=0, longitude=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initializeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /** Default Map is Initialize */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void initializeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            // googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            // R.id.map)).getMap();

            supportMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map));
            googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

            if (googleMap != null) {
                displayMap();
            }
        }
    }

    /** Display The Current Location on Map */
    private void displayMap() {
        // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // Create a criteria Object to retrieve provider
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

                // Get the name of best provider
                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                // Get Current Location
                Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                // set Map Type
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

                // Get latitude of Current Location
                latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
                System.out.println("latitude====="+latitude);

                // Get longitude of Current Location
                longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
                System.out.println("longitude====="+longitude);
                // Create a LatLng object for the current location
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                // Show the current location in Google Map
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

                // Zoom in Google map
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                        new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You R Here..."));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initializeMap();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSubmit:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
            intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

My xml file is,

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Could you maybe make a small self contained example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874677/finding-location-on-google-map/19874802#19874802

Comment: @ Haresh Chhelana It display again same problem. latitude and longitude value is 0. but map is currectly display in cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create separate service class and implements it with LocationListener :

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener
{ 
    private final Context mContext;

    //flag for GPS Status 
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    //flag for network status 
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; 
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    //The minimum distance to change updates in metters 
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; //10 metters

    //The minimum time beetwen updates in milliseconds 
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    //Declaring a Location Manager 
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) 
    { 
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation(); 
    } 

    public Location getLocation() 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            //getting GPS status 
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            //getting network status 
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
            { 
                // no network provider is enabled 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                //First get location from Network Provider 
                if (isNetworkEnabled)
                { 
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    Log.d("Network", "Network");

                    if (locationManager != null)
                    { 
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        updateGPSCoordinates(); 
                    } 
                } 

                //if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services 
                if (isGPSEnabled)
                { 
                    if (location == null) 
                    { 
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                        if (locationManager != null)
                        { 
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            updateGPSCoordinates(); 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        { 
            //e.printStackTrace(); 
            Log.e("Error : Location", "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
        } 

        return location; 
    } 

    public void updateGPSCoordinates() 
    { 
        if (location != null) 
        { 
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Stop using GPS listener 
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app 
     */ 

    public void stopUsingGPS() 
    { 
        if (locationManager != null)
        { 
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Function to get latitude 
     */ 
    public double getLatitude() 
    { 
        if (location != null) 
        { 
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        } 

        return latitude;
    } 

    /** 
     * Function to get longitude 
     */ 
    public double getLongitude() 
    { 
        if (location != null) 
        { 
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        } 

        return longitude;
    } 

    /** 
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled 
     */ 
    public boolean canGetLocation() 
    { 
        return this.canGetLocation;
    } 

//    /** 
//     * Function to show settings alert dialog 
//     */ 
//    public void showSettingsAlert() 
//    { 
//        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
// 
//        //Setting Dialog Title 
//        alertDialog.setTitle(R.string.GPSAlertDialogTitle);
// 
//        //Setting Dialog Message 
//        alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.GPSAlertDialogMessage);
// 
//        //On Pressing Setting button 
//        alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
//        {    
//            @Override 
//            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
//            { 
//                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
//                mContext.startActivity(intent);
//            } 
//        }); 
// 
//        //On pressing cancel button 
//        alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
//        {    
//            @Override 
//            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
//            { 
//                dialog.cancel();
//            } 
//        }); 
// 
//        alertDialog.show();
//    } 

    /** 
     * Get list of address by latitude and longitude 
     * @return null or List<Address> 
     */ 
    public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context)
    { 
        if (location != null) 
        { 
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
            try  
            { 
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                return addresses;
            }  
            catch (IOException e) 
            { 
                //e.printStackTrace(); 
                Log.e("Error : Geocoder", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder", e);
            } 
        } 

        return null; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Try to get AddressLine 
     * @return null or addressLine 
     */ 
    public String getAddressLine(Context context)
    { 
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
        { 
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

            return addressLine;
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return null; 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Try to get Locality 
     * @return null or locality 
     */ 
    public String getLocality(Context context)
    { 
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
        { 
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();

            return locality;
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return null; 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Try to get Postal Code 
     * @return null or postalCode 
     */ 
    public String getPostalCode(Context context)
    { 
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
        { 
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

            return postalCode;
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return null; 
        } 
    } 

    /** 
     * Try to get CountryName 
     * @return null or postalCode 
     */ 
    public String getCountryName(Context context)
    { 
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0)
        { 
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String countryName = address.getCountryName();

            return countryName;
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return null; 
        } 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)  
    {    
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {    
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {    
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
    {    
    } 

    @Override 
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
    { 
        return null; 
    } 
}
```

Now you can get easily latitude and longitude

```
GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(mContext);
latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();
```

Do not forget to add permissions in manifest file.
Cheers

Comment: But I am Using Google map V2. Is it for V2?

Comment: It is again Display 0.0 value of latitude and longitude. Current position is display in map correctly but print the latitude and longitude value is 0.0. what is the solution for it?

Comment: Are you using Emulator or Device ?

Comment: Can I Implement or Create Browswr key or android key for using Google map?

Comment: where is a declare <fragment
android:id="@+id/map"    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" /> in xml file?

Comment: here is the step by step tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Thanks for my help. I can run googlemap successfully and get latitude and longitude correctly.very helpful your demo for me. Thanks once again.